# Is there a way to copy files from VMWare client without the machine running?

Tags: macos, vmware-workstation

I updated to Mac OS-X 10.7.4, and the client stopped working.

I have dev files which I stupidly haven't backed up. Does someone know any way to restore the files on the client or to get into "safe mode" which maybe let me do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a KB from VMware that explains how you can mount VM disks without actually powering on the VM: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010989